# How to creat a countdown timer with the same output for all visitors using Rails and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, timezone, dst

I would like to create a countdown timer to show my visitors how many **days & hours & minutes** still before launching our product

I would like to be able to **choose a datetime of launch** from a date-picker and **choose for which timezone that datetime is** (i.e Central America CST) from a select input

the user will only see something like this :

```
the product will be launched Sun, 28 Oct 2013 CST time
Still : 3 days 5 hours 30 min 10 sec
```

I need that timer to be correct even if the user has a wrong datetime in his/her local computer.

Also I would like to avoid the problem of local timezone, DST (Daylight Saving Time) and such things ...

**Update :**

I've tried this :

(if for example I choose from the datepicker a datetime (let's say **03-07-2015 23:59:59**) to be the date of the launch, and from the select input I choose the timezone : **Pacific Time (US & Canada)**

Then

```
launch_date = '3-07-2015 23:59:59'.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') 
now_in_pacific_time = Time.now.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
time_remain_for_launch = launch_date - now_in_pacific_time
```

So every time the page is rendered I will send an Ajax request to get the remained time in seconds then using jQuery I will calculate how many days,hours,minutes...

Want a confirmation that my code is correct and will not have any problem with DST ... ?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm Look here. Save it into a server launch variable and when the user loads the page, then you calculate the remainder and show it.

Comment: @Зелёный I did a try using only jQuery, but I found myself facing the problem of timezone and DST... so I am wondering if I can solve that using the server side

Comment: @Kaspar the server time normally is in UTC, what if I choose a date related to EST for example ? how I can deal with that even if there is a DST ? this is what I want to know

Comment: What is the difference? What matters is how much time is remaining. You are only going to pass some integers to the client. Then everyone will know that 3 hours is remaining. But if that is not enough for you then go here: http://momentjs.com/docs/ and use that. It is a lot of work done for you allready. Just read the docs and use it in your application.

Comment: I updated my question with what I tried... but still need a confirmation if it's correct